# Ajax form success failure

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
$(function(){
    $('#newnick').submit(function(){
      $('#loadingnick').show();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{ URL::route('setting-change') }}',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data.error){
                    $('#newnickerror').css('display','block');
                    $('#newnickerror').html(data.msg);
                    $('#loadingnick').hide();
                }else {
                    $('#newnicksuccess').show();
                    $('#newnicksuccess').html(data.msg);
                    $('#nickname').html(data.nick);
                    $('#newnickerror').hide();
                    $('#loadingnick').hide();
                }

            }
        })
        return false;
    })
})
```

And it works, so it sends the post to that page, but instead of displaying the success, it redirects me to the page with the json response, which is

```
{"error":true,"msg":"Username already exists"}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to fix: the JSON payload you received has an error message, and your code handles it. Your problem, if any, is on the server side, not in the JS code.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy My code does not handle it, instead of handling the json data given, it redirects me to url:

Comment: are you saying you never reach the success function? If you put a breakpoint in it, you don't reach it?

Comment: Put `console.log("123")` inside success and err callbacks to see where  the code is going and check the network inspector in chrome to see the exact packet transfer. You may have to put `return false` somewhere in success or error callback to avoid page redirection after making a `POST` request.

Comment: @vinit I put return false, still the same. Also, it worked before adding a js needed for the main page, but i don't see how that can interfere with this code

Comment: Did you try and put the console logs and understand the code flow and packet transfer. put the logs and check the console in chrome inspector, and network tabs. That is the best way to approach these minor issues during development.

Comment: I remember something like this happened for me before. I don't remember how I resolved it. I'll let you when I remember.

Comment: @vinit the console.log will only work if the success is running. My whole code is not working, the redirect was due to 
"form action=''". It worked before adding some .js files. How can those files make this code not work?

Comment: @vinit 
I removed newly added files one by one, and by removing this file it worked. "bootstrap-editable.min.js". The only problem is that this file is just a simple plugin, but still, withouth it, some scripts do not work. what should i do?

Comment: One thing you can try is, when you bind the `submit` event on `#newnick` using `$('#newnick').submit(function(){` you can forcibly prevent the default behavior of post submission by `e.preventDefault()`, where `e` will the argument passed to the callback function as in `$('#newnick').submit(function(e){`

Comment: @vinit i have made it work with the code i had, but i had to remove one important script, and now i'm trying to fix it. What can prevent this code from working, knowing that #newnick is never used in other scripts ?